# Why do i get Forbidden <403> error while trying to start Grails 3+ on windows?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am trying to do a project using Grails and I'm really new to this subject.
I also searched and there's another similar question without a proper answer.

Anyway, I installed Grails both 3.2.9 and 3.3.0 M1 versions:

```
C:\Users\acer>grails -version
| Grails Version: 3.2.9
| Groovy Version: 2.4.10
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_102
```

And I'm getting the same Error when I'm trying to create an application.

```
 Resolving dependencies..
Error |
Error occurred running Grails CLI: Forbidden (403) (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden (403)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.handleStatus(HttpTransporter.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:317)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:299)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:291)
    at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:53)
    at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:49)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.MavenProfileRepository.<init>(MavenProfileRepository.groovy:53)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.createMavenProfileRepository(GrailsCli.groovy:334)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:235)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)

Error |
Error occurred running Grails CLI: Forbidden (403)
```

It's really important for my project
I apreciate any help or suggestion in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it's happening during dependency resolution. Those dependencies would likely be first coming from https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/, as found in build.gradle, if you could get an app created.  It looks like you're maybe having trouble accessing that repository.  Confirm you can access that URL from your machine and try again.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i actually can't any grails command and i face the same error ... but im trying to reach that url using proxy

Answer (score 0):

You system is actually identify Grails Version: 3.2.9
It happens for project build issue. You need to rebuild your project by running this command

```
grails clean
```

Comment: Actually, that wasn't the problem because I couldn't make any project.
It happened because grails repository was filtered in my region and I fixed it by using a proxy. but tnx anyway :)